# The columns and rows in the Crystal report viewer is not displayed properly in firefox but working in IE 7 and above

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using VS 2005,ASP.net,crystal report 10.
I have a webapplication with crystal report viewer which displays a crystal report on it.The columns and rows in the Crystal report viewer is not displayed properly in firefox. but those are working in IE 7 and above properly

Thanks in advance
George

Comment: Please give your code

Comment: and how am I going to help you when you have not provided enough information.

Comment: sumon banergie,amazing  . the design of crystal report viewer is included in the question now

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring your Firefox to factory default state before that save any valuable information from Firefox. ie try to Reset the Firefox
 To reset your Firefox try this :

**1.Go to Firefox > Help > Troubleshooting Information. 
                2.Click the "Reset Firefox" button.
                3.Firefox will close and reset. After Firefox is done, it will show a window   with the information that is imported. Click Finish.
4.Firefox will open with all factory defaults applied.**

Try this and see it works ...